# Java my print doesn't work out of the for or somestimes in too I dont know the error, I changed the IDE too :(

Tags: java

So thats the code i made for print the odd and pair numbers and at the final of the code I was expecting to print, but it dont print and idk why, the logic might be right, right ?

```
package Testes;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double array[] = new double[10];
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter =1;
        int par=0, impar=0;
        while(counter<=11)
        {
            System.out.println("Digite o número "+counter);
            array[counter] = read.nextInt();
            counter++;
            if(array[counter]%2==0)
            {
               par = par+1;

            }
            if(array[counter]%2!=0)
            {
                impar = impar+1;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("Tem "+par+" números pares");
        System.out.println("Tem "+impar+" números impares");

        
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you enter 11 numbers?

Comment: This will generate a [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) once your counter hits 10+ since an array starts from 0 and will have a max index of 1 less than the given array size.

Comment: Also, why are you making your array hold `double` values when you're reading input as `int` values?

Comment: The -1 was probably given because not enough troubleshooting was done before posting the question. You could have run it through a debugger and from that you would have found your answer without even posting. You could also have added more print statements to print out each step of the code if you don't have a debugger to use.  This is simple code with a simple answer. Try to do more troubleshooting in the future before posting. You will benefit more from learning to troubleshoot, than from having the community give you the answers. Hope this helps in your continued education and growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is corrected code to count odd and even number. Array's are 0's based so you have to start your counter from 0 and it should be till 9 only. Also increment counter at the end

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double array[] = new double[10];
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    int par = 0, impar = 0;
    while (counter <= 9)
    {
        System.out.println("Digite o número " + counter);
        array[counter] = read.nextInt();

        if (array[counter] % 2 == 0)
        {
            par = par + 1;
        }
        if (array[counter] % 2 != 0)
        {
            impar = impar+1;
        }
        counter ++;
    }
    System.out.println("Tem "+par+" números pares");
    System.out.println("Tem "+impar+" números impares");
}
```